# Create a new Swift app reusing some files from another app

Tags: xcode, swift3

I am developing a swift app started by other developers and wound up rewriting most of the code. Additionally, there were a lot of files and storyboard components which were unused even in the old app.

In this process I left the old files in situ and created new files. The new app will not use a storyboard and there are a number of Objective C frameworks and pods I no longer need. I will copy the app delegate file, plist, assets and all swift files which reference each other.

Now the app has become huge and it would seem easier to create a new app using only the new files I want. Can I just drag the files I want, including asset and plist files I want into the new app? I understand that I should run pod install to get new pods.

Comment: "Can I just drag the files I want, including asset and plist files I want into the new app?" What happened when you _tried_ it?

Comment: When I tried deleting files with the delete key they remained indexed. I have not yet tried adding them, clearly I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you can reuse code from other projects **provided they don't have any other dependencies.**
[The developer naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) describe how you can create a framework for portable code, particularly for Cocoa frameworks. If you create frameworks like '*[Swift frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html)*' code is easily portable across projects and is a massive Time saver.
Also you should use a storyboard for your application. It simplifies everything from maintaining that code since you can see it visually. But I digress since this is your prerogative.

Comment: I prefer not to use a storyboard because I can see the code.